# Get the list of scheduled triggers

Tags: azure-data-factory

We are trying to get the Maximum scheduled trigger time from the list of scheduled trigger in ADF

We have one ADF pipeline, which has multiple scheduled trigger. The pipeline will run at 6:10, 6:20, 6:30, 6:40...... till 10 AM UTC at a gap of every 10 minutes. Is there any possible way to get the Max of scheduled trigger i.e. 10 AM UTC in my case.

We have tried with several system variables, but none worked. We might take an API approach to get the job done, but I want to stay native to the ADF world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refer to ADF REST API:[Trigger Runs - Query By Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/triggerruns/querybyfactory).

In the request body,define the `lastUpdatedAfter` and `lastUpdatedBefore` properties,like the below example:

```
{
  "lastUpdatedAfter": "2018-06-16T00:36:44.3345758Z",
  "lastUpdatedBefore": "2018-06-16T00:49:48.3686473Z",
  "filters": [
    {
      "operand": "TriggerName",
      "operator": "Equals",
      "values": [
        "exampleTrigger"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then loop the trigger runs data from response to get the max row.

> We might take an API approach to get the job done

You could use [Azure Http Trigger Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook),or use [Web Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity) in the ADF to call your specific api.

Comment: this approach helped. We had to actually do a little more configuration. To create and App in the AAD and register the ADF there.